# Присвоить значение переменной в зависимости от условия

Tags: python-3.x

Как присвоить результат вычисления переменной? Если допустим при делении или умножении и т.п., получилось число больше(определённого допустим 20) и переменной присвоилось бы этот максимум(20), а если меньше 20 то получившееся число при вычислении. питон 3.7

Comment: [Тернарная условная операция — Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Благодарю! всё так просто ))